# My website gets cloned on 3 different domains, what can I do about that?

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I already contacted Google and the server provider, but now I wanted to block the website by myself.

It used to refresh my page content immeditaly, but now it doesn't do that anymore.

I tried this with Javascript

```
if (location.hostname != "www.mydomain.de") {
    window.location = "https://www.mydomain.de";
}
```

But this of course wasn't working because it didn't refresh the content anymore.

After a lot of research I found that I should put this in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://.*clonedomain\.tk/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://.*clonedomain\.tk/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

I'm not entirely sure what this does. Does it only prevent that other websites can't point on mine and clone it? Or are these lines the reason why the content wont get immeditaly refreshed?

Comment: If your website gets cloned (= content gets copied to other servers) you can take a look at iptables and block the crawler's IP address. Or do you just want to prevent other sites from using sources from your website? (e.g. images)

Comment: probably this could help you: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170026-What-does-enabling-Cloudflare-Hotlink-Protection-do-

Comment: @nbari my domain is not hosted on cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

> Does it only prevent that other websites can't point on mine and clone
>   it?

No, it doesn't. The first rule set for `%{HTTP_REFERER}` is sending any traffic that is directed from the cloned domain to a `403` error page. So only traffic that comes from that site, to your site, will be blocked.

The second rule will do nothing for you, that is saying if the host address is the clone domain, then send it to a `403` error page. However, since the your domain will never match the cloned domain while they're on your domain, that won't do anything.

As maio290 has pointed out, you need to block traffic from that IP address to prevent them from cloning your website, but then, even that is avoidable.

You've taken the correct steps and have informed Google and your service provider. Keep the first rule for blocking referred traffic and see if you can pin point the IP address(es).